What is mean final version firmware ASA 5525-x
Please advise, when reading the “Release Notes for the Cisco ASA Series, 9.17(x) ” I saw the following:
ASA 9.14(x) was the final version for the ASA 5525-X"
But the current version of our Cisco ASA 5525-x is 9.17(1)
Do I understand correctly that you can continue to update the firmware, but the new functionality released later does not affect error correction in any way, only the numbers change?

If you go to software.cisco.com 9.14.4 is the latest release published for the 5525-X. Later versions may run, but they aren't published for it. (cisco does rewrite history from time to time.)
